# After upgrading to NextJS 13.5, react-hook-form is appending query parameters that should remain in PUT body to the url

Tags: react-hook-form, next.js13

I upgraded from Next 13.4.2 to Next 13.5 because I heard 13.5 was much faster in development mode. However, now my fetch request can't be routed because something (I think react-hook-form) is adding the PUT body's attributes in the URL.

```
 const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof updateFormValidation>) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setUpdateError("");
    setSuccess("");
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/user", {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ ...values, userId: user.id }),
      });

      if (response.status == 200) {
        setSuccess("Profile successfully updated.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setUpdateError("An error occured while updating.");
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

The form which invokes this onSubmit function tries to update a user's "about" and "email" fields. When the update button is clicked, something (I think react-hook-form) appends the about and email values as query parameters, like so:

> `http://localhost:3000/user?about=test&email=test`

Has anyone else experienced this yet?

Comment: The method is replaced from PUT to GET? Are you sure that the submit of form is the only way to execute that function??

Answer (score 0):

React Hook Form cannot update your URL query params. What you're seeing looks like the default HTML form submit behavior, which leads me to believe that either you're not calling the `handleSubmit` method on the form's onSubmit callback, which calls `event.preventDefault()` to "disable" this behavior, or the Next.js forms API has changed since v13.5.

Comment: I thought react-hook-form's handleSubmit implicitly calls preventDefault for you? I've never had to call preventDefault in any of my form's onSubmit functions that are wrapped by handleSubmit. For this reason I thought react-hook-forms may be the culprit.

Comment: It does during the `handleSubmit` call, yes. Sorry if that wasn't clear. What I'm saying is that it doesn't look like it's being called, so it may be a matter of either Next.js behavior or `handleSubmit` not being called. It's hard to tell without a reproduction.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and what occurred is that my Node version somehow was set back to a 16.x.x. I set it to 18.0.0 and it worked.